# Why is a part of my Python code interpreted diffently when I add a seemingly unrelated part?

Tags: python, interpreter, visa, gpib

Some background: I'm implementing a GUI to interact with equipment via GPIB. The issue arises in this method:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import visa #PyVisa Package. pyvisa.readthedocs.io
from time import sleep
import numpy as np #NumPy Package. Scipy.org

def oneDSweep():
Voltage =[]
Current =[]
Source = []
try:
    #Gate = parseGate(Gate1Input.get()) #Not implemented yet.
    Min = float(Gate1MinInput.get()) #Add a check for valid input
    #if Min < .001:
            #Throw exception
    Max = float(Gate1MaxInput.get()) #Add a check for valid input
    VoltageInterval = .02 #Prompt user for interval?
    rm = visa.ResourceManager()
    SIM900 = rm.open_resource("GPIB0::1::INSTR") #Add a check that session is open.

    x = 0
    Volt = Min
    while Volt <= Max:
        SIM900.write("SNDT 1, 'VOLT " + str(Volt) + "'") #Set voltage.
        SIM900.write("SNDT 7, 'VOLT? 1'") #Ask a port for voltage.
        Vnow = SIM900.query("GETN? 7, 50") #Retrieve data from previous port.
        Vnow = Vnow[6:15]
        Vnow = float(Vnow) ############Error location
        Voltage = np.append(Voltage, Vnow)

        SIM900.write("SNDT 1, 'VOLT?'") #Ask a different port for voltage.
        Snow = SIM900.query("GETN? 1, 50") #Retrieve data.
        print(Snow) #Debugging method. Probably not problematic.
        Snow = Snow[4:]
        Snow = float(Snow)

        sleep(1) #Add a delay for science reasons.
        #The code below helps the while loop act like a for loop.
        x = x+1
        Volt = Min + VoltageInterval*x
        Volt = float(truncate(Volt, 7))

finally:
    print(Voltage)
    print(Source)
    Voltage.tofile("output.txt.",sep=",")
    SIM900.write("FLSH")#Flush the ports' memories to ensure no bad data stays there.
```

I get a simple ValueError at the marked location during the first pass of the while loop; Python says it cannot convert the string to a float(more on this later). However, simply remove these five lines of code:

```
    SIM900.write("SNDT 1, 'VOLT?'")
    Snow = SIM900.query("GETN? 1, 50")
    print(Snow)
    Snow = Snow[4:]
    Snow = float(Snow)
```

and the program runs perfectly. I understand the source of the error. With those lines added, when I send these two lines to my instrument:

```
    SIM900.write("SNDT 7, 'VOLT? 1'")
    Vnow = SIM900.query("GETN? 7, 50")
```

I get essentially a null error. `#3000` is returned, which is a blank message the machine sends when it is asked to output data and it has none to output. However, these same two lines produce something like `#3006 00.003` when the four lines I mentioned are excluded from the program. In other words, simply adding those four lines to my program has changed the message sent to the instrument at the beginning of the while loop, despite adding them near the end.

I am convinced that Python's interpreter is at fault here. Earlier, I was cleaning up my code and discovered that one particular set of quotes, when changed from `'` to `"`, produced this same error, despite no other quote pair exhibiting this behavior, even within the same line. My question is, why does the execution of my code change dependent upon unrelated alterations to the code(would also appreciate a fix)? I understand this problem is difficult to replicate given my somewhat specific application, so if there is more information that would be helpful that I can provide, please let me know.

EDIT: Functionality has improved after moving from the command prompt to IDLE. I'm still baffled by what happened, but due to my meager command prompt skills, I can't provide any proof. Please close this question.

Comment: Can you post the error and stacktrace?  It's hard for me to think that Python's +10 year old, battletested interpreter is broken

Comment: You should include the full error traceback you're gettings

Comment: Print the value of the float before mapping it to a string and see what it is saying.  Most likely, it has non-numeric characters

Comment: *adding those four lines to my program has changed the message sent to the instrument at the beginning of the while loop, despite adding them near the end.  I am convinced that Python's interpreter is at fault*    Why?  You already isolated the problem.  Debug `Voltage` and you'll probably see a valid value for the first time through the loop, before the offending code caused the null response from your device.

Comment: Like I said, I understand the source of the error. My instrument sends back a string that does not work with my string slicing code, and I get a ValueError. The problem is, this ValueError ONLY occurs when the Snow block is added. Without the Snow block, which has no impact on the Vnow, block, no error is sent.

Comment: Agreed with @Juan Tomas. You seem to be assuming that those lines affect something that happens *before* them, but it's much more likely it's having an effect on a *future* iteration of the loop.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Traceback: File "beta.py", line 70, in oneDSweep. Vnow = float(Vnow). ValueError: could not convert string to float. EDIT:  Also, I'm not claiming the interpreter is broken. It might just be doing something by design that does not mesh with my application. I would like to know what that is.

Comment: "Without the Snow block, **which has no impact on the Vnow, block**, no error is sent." The part I emphasized is almost certainly not true (based on your own evidence). Why do you believe it?

Comment: @smarx because the while loop fails on the first iteration, before the Snow block is ever touched. I previously intentionally changed the Snow block so that it would give a runtime error, but the loop never reached that point. But again, when that block was deleted, the program ran fine.

Comment: @B.Bush You're making an extraordinary claim, so you'll need to provide extraordinary evidence. Simplify the code down to the minimum to reproduce the error, put `print` statements everywhere, and share the output.

Comment: @B.Bush Another suggestion: get rid of the `while` loop altogether, since you claim it's not actually looping.

Comment: Agreed.  I want to see some serious debug armature around the `Vnow` block, before I'll accept that it's failing on the first iteration.

Comment: Using a mock instrument would also be helpful.    I'm not familiar with the instrument being used, but I wonder if "SNDT 7, 'VOLT? 1'"  should be a query rather than a write.  Using a mock which definitely does not respond to the write would eliminate that possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

Python is telling you exactly what is wrong with your code -- a `ValueError`.  It even gives you the exact line number and the value that is causing the problem.

```
'#3006 00.003'
```

That is the value of `SNOW` that is being printed out.  Then you do this

```
SNOW = SNOW[4:]
```

Now `SNOW` is

```
'6 00.003'
```

You then try to call `float()` on this string.  `6 00.003` can't be converted to a float because it's a nonsensical number.

Comment: That is NOT the value of Snow. That is the value I obtain for Vnow when the Snow block is excluded. When the Snow block is added, I get Vnow = `#3000`, the null result. The Snow block is never even touched during runtime, because when it is included, the Vnow block fails.

Comment: Well, both blocks are interacting with the same object -- `SIM900` -- so it's not surprising that adding or removing one block affects the other.  Have you verified that the while loop hasn't run through a cycle yet?  Maybe print something at the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this before, working on proof right now.

Answer (score 2):

> I am convinced that Python's interpreter is at fault here. Earlier, I was cleaning up my code and discovered that one particular set of quotes, when changed from ' to ", produced this same error, despite no other quote pair exhibiting this behavior, even within the same line.

Python generates exactly the same bytecode for single and double quoted strings (unless embedded quotes are involved, of course). So either the environment you're running your script in is *seriously* broken (I'm counting the python interpreter as part of the "environment"), or your diagnosis is incorrect. I'd put my money on the second.

Here's an alternative explanation. For whatever reason, the hardware you hooked up is returning inconsistent results. So one time you get what you expect, the next time you get an error-- you think your changes to the code account for the differences, but there's no relationship between cause and effect and you end up pulling your hair out. When you run *the same* code several times in a row, do you get consistent results? I.e. do you consistently get the odd behavior? Even if you do, the problem must be with the hardware or the hookup, not with Python.

Comment: Yes, I did get consistent behavior. The thing is, the code I added never reached the instrument I was interacting with.The instrument may change behavior when sent new code, but _the added code was never sent to the instrument_. The block before, which previously worked correctly, failed and caused the program to exit.

Comment: Well, I question whether you can really be sure that what you assert is true. Are you aware that stdout and stderr have different buffering modes, and can appear out of sequence? Print to stderr, not stdout, and you may be surprised.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this. However, I'm using a third party tool that monitors all activity to and from the instrument in question, and it confirms my story. Does this mean that print statements are unreliable when debugging?

Comment: Print statements are very reliable if you use them correctly: Don't mix stdin and stderr, or adjust the buffering. But you are using some unidentified hardware and a third party tool you haven't named, and you're *certain* that the faulty component is Python, the most widely used of the three? Good luck with that.